# sqlalchemy отношения один к многим

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

есть три таблицы:

```
import datetime
import sqlalchemy
from .db_session import SqlAlchemyBase
from sqlalchemy import orm
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin


class User(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                           primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    about = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String,
                              index=True, unique=True, nullable=True)

    picture_path = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)

    hashed_password = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    created_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime,
                                     default=datetime.datetime.now)

    news = orm.relation("News", back_populates='user')
    comments = orm.relation('Comments', back_populates='user')


class News(SqlAlchemyBase, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'news'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    content = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    created_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_private = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, default=False)
    user_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    picture_path = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)

    reacted_count = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, default=0)

    user = orm.relation('User')
    comments = orm.relation('Comments', back_populates='news')


class Comments(SqlAlchemyBase, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("users.id"))
    news_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("news.id"))

    created_data = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    is_private = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, default=False, nullable=True)

    comment = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)

    user = orm.relation('User')
    news = orm.relation('News')
```

три таблицы: пользователи, новости, комментарии.
новость относится к пользователи
комментарий относится к пользователю, новости

когда я создаю новость `user.news.append(news)`, то все нормально, но логично, что не получится связать комментарий сразу с двумя таблицами таким способом, даже если я один из атрибутов укажу вручную (`comment.user = user`), выдает ошибку: `raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Comments at 0x2821ec47d00>' is already attached to session '5' (this is '4')`
вопрос: есть ли способ установить связь сразу к двум таблицам? например попробовать через `orm.relationship` (но я, если честно, не совсем понимаю как он работает) или как-то по-другому указывать вручную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, оказалось все достаточно просто:

```
db_sess = create_session()
comment = Comments(comment=data, news_id=news_id, user_id=user_id,
                           is_private=is_private, news=news, user=user)
db_sess.add(comment)
db_sess.commit()
```

нужно было просто добавить `user` и `news` вручную, и только потом добавлять `comment` непосредственно в таблицу.